# How can I add customer specific price for configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, customer-group

I have configured product X with configure attribute size.

```
**Size** 8
**Price**
Group1 = 10
Group2 = 20
Group3 = 30

**Size** 9
**Price**
Group1 = 10.5
Group2 = 25
Group3 = 32
```

I have 2 simple products which are assigned as associated products to a configurable product. Each simple product has a different price for different customer groups, so I want same logic when I convert it to configure product.
How can i do this in Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

You set the **price** by `Customer Group` only on the `simple product` variant, nothing needs to be configured on the `configurable product`.

When a user of that specific `Customer Group` is logged in, they will see their `customer specific price` for each variant (in this case size) as they select it on product page.

To create a `Customer Group`:

1. Navigate to **Customers > Customer Groups**.
2. Click **Add New Customer Group**
3. Enter **Group Name**
4. Select **Tax Class**
5. Click **Save Customer Group**

To assign a specific **Customer** to a specific `Customer Group`:

1. Navigate to **Customers > Manage Customers**
2. Click on the **Customer** you would like to assign to a `Customer Group`
3. Click **Account Information** from the left side menu
4. Select the **Customer Group** from the **Group** dropdown
5. Click **Save Customer**

After configuring, **reindex** and **clear cache**.

Now, **when that customer is logged in**, they will see whatever price is set for each variant of that product based on the customer group they are assigned to.